# Parsec custom while loop parser only parses one statement in loop body

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to write a parser to parse a loop in the following form:

```
(:= x 0)
Do ((< x 10))-> 
         (:= x (+ x 1))
         print(x)
Od
```

What's occurring however is that my parser can only work for a loop whose body contains only one statement. To parse more than one statement, the body above would have to be written in the following way:

```
(:= x (+ x 1))(:= x 20)
```

I have tried to use delimiters such as semi-colons to try and force the parser to allow for loop body parsing to be taken line by line the above behaviour persists such that it would have to be written like: `(:= x (+ x 1));(:= x 20)` instead of on separate lines.

Please find my parsers below:

```
parsersHStatement :: Parser HStatement
parsersHStatement = try (parsePrint) <|> try (parseDo) <|> try (parseEval)

parseLoopBody :: Parser [HStatement]
parseLoopBody = many1 $ parsersHStatement

parseDo :: Parser HStatement
parseDo = do
     spaces
     _ <- string "Do"
     spaces
     _ <- string "("
     p <- try (parseExpr) <|> try (parseBool)
     _ <- string ")->"
     spaces
     q <-  parseLoopBody <* spaces
     spaces
     _ <- string "Od"
     return $ Do p q

parseEval :: Parser HStatement
parseEval = liftM Eval $ parsersHVal

parsersHVal :: Parser HVal
parsersHVal = try (parseAssign) <|> try (parsePrimitiveValue) <|> try (parseExpr)

parsePrint :: Parser HStatement
parsePrint = string "print(" *> parsersHVal <* string ")" >>= (return . Print)

parseExpr :: Parser HVal
parseExpr = do
        char '('
        spaces
        op <- try (parseOperation)
        spaces
        x  <- try (sepBy (parseExpr <|> parseVarOrInt) spaces)
        spaces
        char ')'
        return $ Expr op x

parseBool :: Parser HVal
parseBool = classifyBool <$> ( (string "True") <|> (string "False") )
  where
    classifyBool "True"  = Bool True
    classifyBool "False" = Bool False
```

Within `parseLoopBody`, I tried 'feeding' `spaces` (`many1 $ spaces *> ...`) but nothing would parse then.

The following is the ADT:

```
data HVal
  = Integer  Integer
  | Var      String
  | Bool     Bool
  | List     [HVal]
  | Expr     Operation [HVal]
  | Assign   HVal HVal
  deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

data HStatement
  = Eval  HVal -- Bridge between HVal and HStatement
  | Print HVal
  | Do    HVal [HStatement]
  deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
```

`parseDo` was altered to the following :

```
parseDo :: Parser HStatement
parseDo = do
      string "Do"
      spaces
      string "("
      p <- try (parseExpr) <|> try (parseBool)
      string ")->"
      spaces
      q <-  many1 $ parsersHStatement
      spaces
      string "Od"
      return $ Do p q
```

This allows for the parsing of two statements but the second statement breaks the loop.

Comment: Can you also show the code of `parsersHStatement`?

Comment: @Noughtmare Of course! I'll make the edit but it involves some of the other parsers in the ADT!

Comment: Is the question "Why does `many1 $ parsersHStatement` not allow spaces between HStatements?"

Comment: More or less yes. To be more specific, how come it can't be line by line?

Comment: Does `parseLoopBody = many1 $ parsersHStatement *> spaces` get you where you need to go?

Comment: Sadly no, I receive an error that it gives the type ``` ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [()]``` rather than ```Parser [HStatement]```. Could it be something regarding the other parsers in that by themselves they are fine but cobbled together into a loop body they don't work.

Comment: Currently making some leeway, I changed ```parseDo``` slightly and can now parse two statements in the body but the second breaks the loop. The altered parser will be edited in now.

Comment: Yes, of course I meant `<*` not `*>`. I always forget whether the arrow points at the one that gets kept or the one that's ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around, it seemed that the error lay responsible on the function `parseEval`. This was changed to:

```
parseEval :: Parser HStatement
parseEval = do
         x <- try (parseAssign) <|> try (parseExpr)
         spaces
         return $ Eval x
```

Furthermore my `parseDo` function was changed to:

```
parseDo :: Parser HStatement
parseDo = do
      string "Do"
      spaces
      string "("
      p <- try (parseExpr) <|> try (parseBool)
      string ")->"
      spaces
      q <-  many1 $ parsersHStatement
      spaces
      string "Od"
      return $ Do p q
```